# send c# array to php web service

Tags: c#, php, web-services

i want to know how to send C# array to php web service .
here c# application is in client and php webpage is in  server,this php web service get that array and store in database

Comment: You will not find anyone here to just do the work for you. You need to try something for yourself first and then come back if you have a more specific problem, and include your current attempts

Comment: show what you have tried so far , refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly send array to php service but what you can do is create a string separated by ','(coma) & then send it in url or as response,

at server side you can just split it & here you get your ans.

Another way is as Elliot said but you need some JSON knowledge.

Comment: What if some of the elements contain commas? Your solution would be problematic

Comment: of course then you should go with another delimiter which does not contain problems.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

1. Convert your data to JSON or XML using **serialization** (according to what your service consumes).
2. Create HTTP POST Query, look at MSDN for classes for doing it.
3. Put your converted data in the query body.
4. Send it.

Comment: "must" is a strong word, I think this is just your opinion of how it should be done... there are many ways

Comment: As I know, this is the most generic one :)